# UpdateDE row with 'Is_Processed' from a batch 'notification-style' email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, dataextensions

I have a journey which includes a response capture element via Interactive Forms and a bespoke CloudPages landing page. There's a daily extract automation to pull all responses within the last 24hrs and transfer these to an internal-user directory. At the end of the automation, I have a notification email, alerting the internal user that a new file is available at X location.

At send, I wanted to be able to update a column in the sending DE for rows that were included in the latest file.

Here's what I have so far:

Email / SMS comms directing users to an interactive form or CloudPages landing page
Responses captured into the send DE in the FormData_ columns
Daily automation which selects, extracts, formats, transfers and sends a notification email

However, I'm unable to get the sending DE updated at the time of sending the notification email with success info i.e. Is_Process = '1' and Processed_Date = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())

Here's my notification email code:

```
%%[
var @localDate, @fileName, @dataSourceName, @subscriberKey, @rowsUpdated

set @localDate = SystemDateToLocalDate(Now())
set @dataSourceName = "AMI_NC_Responses_V3"

%%[
 
  SET @fileName = Concat('AMI_NC_Responses_Extract', FormatDate(@localDate, 'YYYYMMDD'),'.csv')
  SET @archiveURL = Concat('F:\docs\ma\C25_Correspondence\01_General\MAP - letters','\AMI_BillData\',@fileName)
  SET @subscriberKey = IsNullDefault(RequestParameter("sk"), "")
  
  /* Update record in journey DE to identify where the record has been processed */
  set @rowsUpdated = UpdateDE(@dataSourceName, 1,"Primary_Contact_ID", @subscriberKey,"Is_Processed", 1,"Processed_Date",@localDate)

]%%
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <title>Notification Email</title>
      <style>
         body {
         background-color: #f6f6f6;
         font-family: sans-serif;
         -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
         font-size: 14px;
         line-height: 1.4;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
         -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
         }
         .body {
         background-color: #f6f6f6;
         width: 100%; 
         }
         .content {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         display: block;
         margin: 0 auto;
         max-width: 580px;
         padding: 10px; 
         }
         .main {
         background: #ffffff;
         border-radius: 3px;
         width: 100%; 
         }
         .footer {
         clear: both;
         margin-top: 30px;
         width: 100%; 
         }
         .footer p,
         .footer span,
         .footer a {
         color: #666666;
         font-size: 12px;
         }
         h1 {
         color: #000000;
         font-family: sans-serif;
         line-height: 1.4;
         margin: 0;
         margin-bottom: 30px; 
         font-size: 24px;
         font-weight: 300;
         }
         p {
         font-family: sans-serif;
         font-size: 14px;
         font-weight: normal;
         margin: 0;
         margin-bottom: 15px; 
         }
         a {
         color: #3498db;
         text-decoration: underline; 
         }
         .apple-link a {
         color: inherit !important;
         font-family: inherit !important;
         font-size: inherit !important;
         font-weight: inherit !important;
         line-height: inherit !important;
         text-decoration: none !important; 
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="content">
         <h1>AMI File Notification</h1>
         <h2>Details</h2>
         <p>The following file is ready: %%=v(@fileName)=%%</p>
         <p><strong>Date Processed:</strong> %%=FormatDate(@localDate, 'l', '', 'en_NZ')=%%</p>
         <p><strong>Time Processed:</strong> %%=FormatDate(@localDate, '', 'hh:mm', 'en_NZ')=%%</p>
         <p><strong>File Location:</strong> <a href="file:///%%=v(@archiveURL)=%%">%%=v(@archiveURL)=%%</a></p>
         
         <div class="footer"><p>Sent from %%Member_Busname%%, %%Member_Addr%%, %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%<span style="display:none;">%%profile_center_url%%</span></p></div>
         <custom name="opencounter" type="tracking"/>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that your email does not understand what you want to define as @subscriberkey:

Current:

```
SET @subscriberKey = IsNullDefault(RequestParameter("sk"), "")
```

requestparameter is used for cloudpages to read out incoming web request parameters, this makes little sense in emails. if this is not correct, then the update line will interpret and "work" technically, but do nothing.

Try to just leverage the personalization string "_subscriberkey" instead.

New:
Replace above line with:

```
SET @subscriberkey = _subscriberkey
```

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_personalization_strings.htm

Comment: silly me, of course requestparameter is! Thank you for refreshing my memory and providing the response above - all sorted now.

Comment: no worries, pls mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question. :)